# grails redirect to wrong url

Tags: rest, grails, groovy

I don't know why, but when I am trying to redirect to specific controller **test1** and action **test2**

```
redirect(controller: "test1", action: "test2", params: [param1: "test", param2: "test"]
```

I am going to the second URL in my UrlMapping:

```
1) "/$param1/$param2"(controller: 'test1', action: 'test2')

2) "/$param1/$param2"(controller: 'test1', action: 'test3')
```

Comment: use different prefixes

Comment: can you show your urlmapping for this?